# Enabling Publishing Feature in Content Type Hub

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, content-type-hub

I am trying to create a custom content type which inherits from Article Page content type and would like to create in content type hub. The issue issue is Article Page is not available in content type hub.

I think activating publishing feature will create Article Page content type in content type hub. Can there be any issues when i publish my custom content type as it is inheriting from Article Page and Article Page content type is already in other sites in tenant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should not be any issues.

The default out-of-the-box Article Page content type (and all other OOTB CTs) contain predefined Content Type IDs, and as Content Type inheritance (=all parents) can be extracted from your custom Content Type ID, the system will know from what OOTB CTs your custom content type is inherited.

"You can construct a valid content type ID using one of two conventions:

- Parent content type ID + two hexadecimal values (the two hexadecimal values cannot be "00")
- Parent content type ID + "00" + hexadecimal GUID"

More about CT inheritance can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543822%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).